# how to read the MS word table content that have different cell widths using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm reading MS Word table content using C#,
 but i don't know how to get the merged cell information.
the table like this:

```
     ---------------------
     | c(1,1)|   c(1,2)  | 
     |--------------------
     | c(2,1)   |  c(2,2)|

     |--------------------
     | c(3,1)            |
     |-------------------|
```

the cell c(3,1) is a merged cell, bu i can't get the information.
my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= doc.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table nowTable = doc.Tables[i];
    for (int rowPos = 1; rowPos <= nowTable.Rows.Count; r
    {
        for (int columPos = 1; columPos <= nowTable.Colum)
        {

            String strContent = nowTable.Cell(rowPos, columPos).Range.Text;                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What exactly do you get instead? Exception? Null value? 2. What `nowTable.Cell(3, 1)` returns? (or `nowTable.Cell(2,0)`, I'm not sure what is the start index)

Comment: how to judge the cell is merged